# Where to specify key and IV value when doing AES encryption/decryption in Android?

Tags: android, encryption, aes, aescryptoserviceprovider

I am working on AES encryption and decryption in android. I have an Audio file which is encrypted using AES/CBC. I have the key and IV (initialization vector).

I have read some links. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788018/android-encryption-decryption-with-aes)

```
SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
```

The SecretkeySpec class used. Where should I use my key and IV values?

And I need to decrypt only first 256 bytes data only. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In your code snippet, `raw` is your key (as a byte array):

```
SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
//                                         ^^^ this is your key
```

Of course, if you have your key as a hex string, you'll need to [convert it to bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18714790/474189).

When encrypting, you can either specify an IV yourself or let a random one be generated. If you want to specify yourself, use:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"); // adjust padding
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(...));
```

if you want to use an automatic one, be sure to record which one was chosen by calling

```
cipher.getIV();
```

For decryption, you must specify the IV and you do so using an `IvParameterSpec`, just like with encryption.

> And I need to decrypt only first 256 bytes data only. How can I achieve this?

Consider using a `CipherInputStream` and read only 256 bytes from it.